# Incrementing case number in a function?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm just learning C and I'm having trouble making my code increment the dayName on the same printf function.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGH_OF_WEEK 7

int main()
{
    int daysOfWeek[LENGH_OF_WEEK] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    char* dayName = NULL;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < LENGH_OF_WEEK; i++)
{
    switch (daysOfWeek[i])
    {
    case 0: dayName = "Sunday"; break;
    case 1: dayName = "Monday"; break;
    case 2: dayName = "Tuesday"; break;
    case 3: dayName = "Wednesday"; break;
    case 4: dayName = "Thursday"; break;
    case 5: dayName = "Friday"; break;
    case 6: dayName = "Saturday"; break;
    }

    printf("%s, %s Happy Days\n", dayName, dayName);
}

return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get my console to sing Happy Days, but it just says the dayName twice and I would like to figure out how to make it say "Saturday, what a day! Groovin' all week with you!" for case 6.

Comment: Surely the song goes "Sunday, Monday Happy Days!" and so on

Comment: Sunday and Monday are **not** happy days. Friday is.

Comment: The entire thing with the `daysOfWeek` array is just confusing. It's a mapping of integers ranged 0..6 to themselves, i.e. it has no point. This code is very confusing.

Comment: It says it twice, b/c you told it to do so: `printf("%s, %s Happy Days\n", dayName, dayName);`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Spot On!

Comment: A quick remainder of the song would not hurt...

Comment: Maroun, in the Tutorial I viewed, he forgot to add Case 1 and he said, he forgot Monday and said it wouldn't really be a bad thing because he hated Mondays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my version of the classic theme song.  Not using a switch statement, sorry

```
#include <stdio.h>


char *day[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
int main()
{

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i+=2)
{
    printf("%s, %s Happy Days\n", day[i], day[i+1]);
}
printf("Saturday, what a day\n Groovin' all week with you!\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pragmatist's answer to your specific question would probably just to have 6 or 7 complete strings, one for each day ("Sunday, Monday Happy Days", "Monday, Tuesday Happy Days", etc.)

But as you're really just experimenting, if you pull out your mapping of indices to day names into a separate function:

```
const char* MapIndexToDayName(int dayIndex)
{
    switch(dayIndex)
    {
    case 0: 
        return "Sunday";
   ... etc.
    }
}
```

Then you can perhaps see more easily how you have a single `printf`, into which you pass the result of calling this function, both with 'today' and with 'today + 1'

If you've got a special case for Saturday, then just add an 'if' to test for that day and handle the special case separately, or run the loop through the consistent early part of the week, and add a second printf after the loop finishes, to cope with the last day.

Answer (score 1):

I think the structure of your code leaves a lot to be desired.

I didn't understand the point of the `daysOfWeek` array at all, it just maps 0 to 0, 1 to 1, and so on.

Perhaps you should use something like this:

```
typedef enum {
  DAY_MONDAY = 0,
  DAY_TUESDAY,
  DAY_WEDNESDAY,
  DAY_THURSDAY,
  DAY_FRIDAY,
  DAY_SATURDAY,
  DAY_SUNDAY
} DayOfWeek;
```

and then write a function to give you the name of each day:

```
const char * name_of_day(DayOfWeek day)
{
  switch(day)
  {
  case DAY_MONDAY:
    return "Monday";
  case DAY_TUESDAY:
    return "Tuesday";
  /* and so on */
  }
}
```

Then try again to formulate the program that prints the song lyrics, but use `DayOfWeek` values to represent days of the week, and the `name_of_day()` function to give you a string representation of such a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to acheive what you wanted, it is better if you define a string arrays(in other words two dimensional character arrays) and loop and access the daynames from that array. If you want a simpler approach which is closer to your code, the below code works.

```
for (i = 0; i < LENGH_OF_WEEK; i+=2)
{
    switch (daysOfWeek[i])
    {
       case 0: string = "Sunday, Monday"; break;
       case 2: string = "Tuesday, Wednesday"; break;
       case 4: string = "Thursday, Friday"; break;
    }

    printf("%s, Happy Days.\n", string);
}

printf("Saturday, What a day, \n Groovin' all week with you. \n", string);
```

Comment: I have edited the code to ensure Happy Days is only used once

Answer (score 1):

```
    char *WeekdayName[] = {
        "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    char** dayName = WeekdayName;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < LENGH_OF_WEEK; i++) {
        printf("%s, ", *dayName++);
        if(i!=6)
            printf("%s Happy Days\n", *dayName);
        else
            printf("what a day! Groovin' all week with you!\n");
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the repeated day, it will say "Sunday, Sunday Happy Days", not "Sunday, Monday Happy Days"

Comment: @LauraKnight I did not know because they do not know the song. Thank you for letting me know.